# API call to NodeJs/Express Server throws 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' after switching to SSL

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ssl, express, https

**My environment**

Client - AngularJS with restangular hosted on amazon with cloudflare controlling my DNS

Server - NodeJS/Express 4.0 also hosted on amazon with cloudflare controlling my DNS

**The problem**

Using cloudflares ok'd ports(8080) for http I am able to have angular server make requests to the node server just fine with no issues. CORS is installed and works fine.

[image: success message]

After enabling SSL to both servers and using ports (2053) I started getting Preflight request errors from the node server.

[image: error message]

**Attempted**

The first thing I attempted was to make sure I specify my white-list for CORS on my node server, with no luck. Same preflight error.

```
var cors                = require('cors');
app.use(cors({origin: 'https://app.lynksup.com'}));
```

I then tried to add my own CORS Setup, with no luck as well

```
app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://app.lynksup.com");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
  next();
});
```

I saw a few users doing this, but it also did not work.

```
app.option('*', function(req, res){
    res.send(200);
});
```

My angular app also contains the fallowing in the config section, but I have tried with and without.

```
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
```

Here is a slim version of my node server for reference

```
var ManagementClient    = require('auth0').ManagementClient;
var http                = require('http');
var express             = require('express');
var bodyParser          = require('body-parser');
var app                 = express();
var jwt                 = require('express-jwt');
var cors                = require('cors');
var morgan              = require('morgan');
var extend              = require('xtend');
var fs                  = require("fs");
var ssl_options = {
   key  : fs.readFileSync("private.key", 'utf8'),
   cert : fs.readFileSync("lynksup.crt", 'utf8')
};

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
//cors
app.use(cors({origin: 'https://app.lynksup.com'}));

// ROUTES 
app.use('/api', router);

var router = express.Router();

router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('log requests...');
    next();
});

router.get('/test', function(req, res) {
    res.json({ message: 'Hello world' });   
});

var port = 2053;
var https = require('https').createServer(ssl_options, app);
https.listen(port);
console.log('API server up and running on: ' + port);
```

Thanks in advance to anyone that can provide some incite to this issues. Its been driving me off the wall, but I'm sure its something simple I'm missing.

Comment: HTTP status 522 is CloudFlare timeout. The OPTIONS request needs a status in the 200s.

Comment: Yea seams as though I get the cloudflare error only when using ssl. Testing this same code but with an HTTP server instead Im able to get by with no issue and no preflight error

Comment: Did you find a solution please? I am facing the same issue with React.